# Why am I getting runtime errors on this code? (C code ran by makefile thru linux)

Tags: c, runtime-error

First time coding in C, coming from C++. I was trying to make a program that solves the K-Neighbors problem. Assuming all locations are points in a 2D plane, it should return the closest k cities when given a list of n cities. After much debugging, it finally complied and ran, but returned a runtime error. I couldn't read the error code, so I don't understand what happened. What did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>  //for printf
#include <stdlib.h> //for malloc, free
#include <math.h>   //for sqrt, pow

struct City {
    double x;
    double y;
    double distance;
};

double get_distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
    return sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2- y1, 2));
}

void make_list(struct City arr[]){
    arr[0].x = 0;       arr[0].y = 0;       arr[0].distance = 0;
    arr[1].x = 110;     arr[1].y = 150;     arr[1].distance = 0;
    arr[2].x = 140;     arr[2].y = 30;      arr[2].distance = 0;
    arr[3].x = 91;      arr[3].y = 70;      arr[3].distance = 0;
    arr[4].x = 172;     arr[4].y = 161;     arr[4].distance = 0;
    arr[5].x = 62;      arr[5].y = 160;     arr[5].distance = 0;
    arr[6].x = 16;      arr[6].y = 163;     arr[6].distance = 0;
    arr[7].x = 161;     arr[7].y = 40;      arr[7].distance = 0;
    arr[8].x = 162;     arr[8].y = 20;      arr[8].distance = 0;
    arr[9].x = 61;      arr[9].y = 117;     arr[9].distance = 0;
}

//time complexity O(n^2)
void insertion_sort(double arr[], int n){
    int i, key, j;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;

        while(j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

int main() {
    int array_size = 10;
    struct City arr[array_size];
    double distances[array_size];
    make_list(arr);

    //Find distance from me and add to sorted distances
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++){
        arr[i].distance = get_distance(arr[0].x, arr[0].y, arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
        insertion_sort(distances, array_size);
    }

    //Print the distances
    int k = 5;
    double temp = 0;
    printf("\nThe %d closest distances are:\n", k);
    if(k < array_size){
        for(int i = 1; i < k; i++){
            temp = distances[i];
            printf("%f\n", temp);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the runtime error? As a first pass, I would suggest pulling the call to the `insertion_sort` function outside the loop, and then I would double check the logic of the function to make sure it’s doing what you intend.  Do you have a debugger like `gdb`?  If so, this looks like a good opportunity to learn how to use it.

Comment: You don't ever store any data in the array `distances`, so when you sort and print it you are operating on garbage.

Comment: To address Nates issue, right after the line ```arr[i].distance = get_distance ...``` in your for loop, put the line ```distances[i] = arr[i].distances```. This will fill up the distances array with the distances. Also, remove the call to insertion sort in the for loop. Just call it once AFTER the for loop like John said. After making these adjustments, I ran your code with the arbitrary example you have, and it worked on my end.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Transitioning from C++ to C I think is probably harder than the other way around (which is what I did).

*This next paragraph has been slightly edited from original answer. Credit to **John Bode** for correcting me about C99 introducing variable-length arrays*

Originally, arrays in C using [ ] could not be declared using a variable as the size like you can in C++. As someone pointed out in a comment, "Since C99, arrays can be declared with a runtime variable, although support is spotty and the feature was made optional in C11. They’re called variable-length arrays and can be useful." So, this implies that it's not working for you since you're current programming environment setup doesn't support it.

If you wanted to try to figure out how to get your programming environment to support this, go ahead. I personally don't know off the top of my head. For you in the context of this problem I think that's a bit of overkill. The easiest thing is just to use macros. Delete `int array_size = 10;` and define it as a macro right above main like `#define array_size 10`. (On a side note, I always like to make macros all caps like ARRAY_SIZE but you don't have to). For your purposes, the readers digest explanation of macros in this context is that here it will act as text replacement. So, everywhere array_size is written, it's equivalent to you literally manually typing in the number 10, or whatever arbitrary size you give it.

Comment: Tried your solution, still didn't work. Now the error code says this: [Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)]

Comment: I was only trying to address the primary issue which is you did something illegal in C. I have no idea if anything else was wrong. For starters, when you say you "tried my solution", do you mean you deleted the variable array_size and made it a macro like ```#define array_size 10```?

Comment: Since C99, arrays *can* be declared with a runtime variable, although support is spotty and the feature was made optional in C11.  They’re called *variable-length arrays* and can be useful.

Comment: Thank you for saying this John, I didn't know that. I will adjust my answer.